# Uploading media to firebase storage takes too long

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am working on a project where I need to save an image or a video to firebase storage. I have this code. It sometimes work but most of the time it is stuck in the `await ref.put(blob)`. Same thing happens in iOS and Android.

```
const upload = async (id: string, uri: string) => {
  const extension = uri.split('.').pop();
  const ref = firebase.storage().ref(`${id}.${extension }`);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    await ref.put(blob);

    const mediaUri = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return mediaUri;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: If the same code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, the problem is more likely in the data that you feed into the code than in the code itself. What is different about your `id` and `uri` values at the times that the code doesn't work? And where does `filename` in your code come from? Is that value also different between when the code works and when it doesn't? Can you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values for `id`, `uri`, and `filename`?

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

May not solve every use case but limiting the image to 1000 for height and width (`maxWidth` and `maxHeight` on React Native) reduced the upload time to 2-5s instead of 10-15s before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).